# ¿Como activo el menú de sugerencia de etiquetas, clases y/o métodos en Eclipse?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

Actualmente estoy aprendiendo Java y Spring y me encuentro que mi editor Eclipse no me genera ayudas/ sugerencias de métodos o clases al escribir código. Esto no solo ocurre con las clases o métodos de Java sino que incluso me ocurre con etiquetas html, etc.

Algo que he visto que si les pasa a otros. Supongo que algo esta deshabilitado o tal vez necesite algún plugin. Me sería de gran ayuda estos atajos.

[image: Adjunto una imágene para que vean a que me refiero.]

Comment: A mi me aparece con alt+espacio o ctrl+espacio, no se si en tu caso funcionara asi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal vez lo tienes desactivado ve a Preferencias :

`Java` > `Editor` > `Content Assist` > `Advanced`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa la documentación "Content Assist Preferences" :
https://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/code_assist.htm

Comment: Ciertamente esa era la solución. Gracias.